# NotSibling: Invalid Constraints

Tags: java, android, xml

While executing my project I came across a problem and I'm not sure what causes it. The error I'm getting is
`"....../file.xml" 41: @+id/secureText is not a sibling in the same ConstraintLayout`

The complete file code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.activities.SpeedTestActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background_main">

    <com.github.anastr.speedviewlib.PointerSpeedometer
        android:id="@+id/speedView"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:speedTextSize="0sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/speedText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="0.00MB/S"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/speedView" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adVBannerSpeedTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/secureText"      // <- the problematic line
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_banner_id1"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/startTest"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/connect_button_background"
        android:text="Start Speed Test"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />  
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

`ConstraintLayout` can only handle the alignment among its children.

```xml
<ConstraintLayout>
    <This>
    <Are>
    <All>
    <Children>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

However when you say to `ConstraintLayout` something like

```xml
<ConstraintLayout>
    <Childrens
         android:layout_below="@id/secureText">
</ConstraintLayout>
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/secureText"/>
```

`ConstraintLayout` will fail to understand you and will not imply that constrain and will give you a warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can align only children of the parent ConstraintLayout.
You haven't got any view with id `secureText` in your ConstraintLayout. Probably you want to set it to `speedText` instead.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I resolved it by updating the Kotlin version.